# Move object from one canvas to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

i Have Canvas A and Canvas B and want to move star object from Canvas A and place it on Canvas B. Is it possible? if yes how can i do it ? for more understanding look picture below 
[image]

Comment: I dont think you can actually move it to the other canvas other than to overlap. You can probably make a copy of your star on canvas A and then create the same star on canvas B?

Comment: Actually I just mis interpreted your question ....deleted my answer...Link for your help: http://jsfiddle.net/uppzL/12/

Comment: thanks for your comments if there won't be another way i will do like we commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a straightforward feature of canvas. You can use some of existing libraries to achieve this or can refer them to write your own code.

The idea includes:

1. register mouse events (up, down, move) on canvas objects
2. maintain mouse drag state (dragging or mousemove)
3. save the object state in variable (copy)
4. repaint the canvas while dragging to give it a proper dragging like look & feel
5. on drop (mouseup) render the object (copied previously) on target canvas